# Deleting field/column of shapefile with OGR/GDAL Python?

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal

Is it possible to delete a field in a shapefile using GDAL with python?

With gdal 2.1.3 (Ubuntu 16.04), I can only see a `CreateField()` method on the layer object. No similar functions to delete a field.

Searching around, I can only find a [ticket](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/2671) discussing the possibility and related rfc35.

Is this function implemented and how to use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use [OGR SQL](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html) `ALTER TABLE` statement to `DROP` the column directly via `ExecuteSQL()`:

```
from osgeo import gdal

ds = gdal.OpenEx("my_shp.shp", gdal.OF_VECTOR | gdal.OF_UPDATE)
ds.ExecuteSQL("ALTER TABLE my_shp DROP COLUMN my_field")
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually see this done by creating a copy of the shapefile, but specifying which fields to include in the copy. Once a copy is made, it's easy enough to delete the original file and rename the copy.

[Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90005/remove-unneeded-columns-from-geographic-data-file) is a simple non-python way. Otherwise, I think you should be able to create a solution based on [this python example](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#filter-and-select-input-shapefile-to-new-output-shapefile-like-ogr2ogr-cli).

Answer (score 2):

To delete a column from the attribute table of a shapefile, I used this:

```
dataSource = driver.Open("MyShapefile.shp", 1) 
layer = dataSource.GetLayer()
layer.DeleteField(4)
```

where 4 is the index of the column I want to delete (starting from 0).

I hope it was what you asked.

Comment: We've just run into this problem. Calling `DeleteField` removes the field from the layer schema, but not from the features within the layer. The docstring says "This function should not be called while there are feature objects in
existence that were obtained or created with the previous layer
definition."

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know the field index of the field u want to delete, do like this:

```
lyr_definition = lyr.GetLayerDefn()
for n in range(lyr_definition.GetFieldCount()):
    field = lyr_definition.GetFieldDefn(n)
    field_name = field.name
    field_index = n ### After the loop u can type: lyr.DeleteField(field_index)
```

Comment: looping through a range can lead to calling a 'none' field in your list of fields if you delete them as you go. I tried to apply the above to a shapefile where i wanted to retain just 3 fields out of about 30. Instead use a while loop, where n <= number of fields. Update n and your number of fields each time you delete a field.

Comment: U are absolutely right, this will work exclusively if u need delete only one field.